# What's the equivalent for LoadVars in flex3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

```
    var lv = new LoadVars();
    var r = new LoadVars();
    lv.action = "update";
            r.onLoad = function(success) 
    {
                //do further logic here
            }
    lv.sendAndLoad("http://example.net/service.php", r, "POST");
```

How to do the above in flex 3?

**UPDATE**

How to do it with `URLLoader` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WITH HTTPService**

```
var vo:Object = new Object;
    vo.action = "update";
    s = new HTTPService();
    s.url = "http://example.net/service.php"
    s.method = "POST";
    s.resultFormat = "e4x"; //or xml or whatever
    s.send(vo);
    s.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onLoad);
```

**WITH URLLoader**

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url here");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();     
vars.action = "update";
request.data = vars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
```

Comment: How to do it with URLLoader ?